# How to block BitBucket merge if target branch isn't on top of specific parent branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

Let's say, using Gitflow, that I have 2 branches, A and B, both off of develop, being worked on simultaneously.

A gets merged back into develop.

What I would like to happen is the following:

A PR gets opened to merge some feature onto B.  If B is behind develop (which it would be now), I want the merge to be blocked, the same way it would if there was a conflict.

Is this possible?  Is this a bad strategy?  Is there a better way to do this in Git?

We're in a situation where we've been developing, then at the very end merge develop back into our feature branches and are left resolving a million conflicts.  I want to find a way to force this up front.  Can somebody help me figure out the right way to handle this?

If this is a duplicate please let me know, I didn't know the right words to search for this.

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server (on-prem)?

Comment: Bitbucket Server (on-prem)

Comment: Are "A" and "B" long running branches?  Or are they feature branches?   If they are feature branches, in my experience it's rare to merge a feature *into* a feature.

Comment: Also, are you talking handful of devs, dozens, or hundreds?  How often is "develop" merged back into all the feature branches?  Once/month?  Once/week?  Mono-repo or single-project-repo?

Comment: A and B are long running branches, similar to develop.  Work gets done on them every day but they don't normally get merged 
back into develop for at least a month or two.  Also it's only dozens of devs.

Comment: Thanks for response - very useful.  One last question:  does the inverse situation ever happen in your shop?  (B merges into 'develop' making A stale, and you want all feature-branches that target A to block?) Blocking the PR's is possible, but probably requires a custom plugin.  I can do it for you.  If the situation is not symmetric, however, and only 'B' ever gets stale, then you can use Bitbucket Server's "automatic merge" feature to keep 'B' up to date automatically.

Comment: Thanks for helping!  The inverse can definitely happen, but typically we would order the long running branches by when they'd be released, so more than likely A will be merged before B.  Sometimes dates change though and B could be merged before A.  I'm interested in the automatic merge feature, I saw something like that in the settings but it looked like it was only for features that were off of master and not develop.  Is it possible to do this with both master and develop? That should fix this problem

Comment: The point of automatic merge is to back-merge production changes (e.g., production bug-fixes) into development to prevent regressions.  By pretending 'develop' is production and 'B' is development you could leverage the feature, but I don't think it's a perfect fit for you.  (Also if the merge fails because of conflicts, someone needs to manually come in and clean that up).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want fast-forward only on your merges.

It will stop the new PR until they rebase off of the new HEAD commit on branch B.

You can enable this in your repository settings.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver059/pull-request-merge-strategies-949255012.html

You can automate this strategy with a hook, but you may have conflicts to deal with.

Comment: I like fast-forward for feature branches (merging into master), but regular merge for merges between long-running branches (e.g., release/1.2.3 <--> master).  Bitbucket's "merge strategy" setting is not able to distinguish between these different cases.  My free [Control Freak](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217635/control-freak-for-bitbucket-server?hosting=server&tab=overview) add-on is better for this.